# Reading zipped folder with empty subdirectories causes problems

Tags: c#, .net, zip, compression

I'm running into a strange problem using ZipFile and ZipArchive with .Net 4.5.

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory takes all content of a directory, including folders that are empty.
If I try to create the same zip file using Windows explorer by right clicking > Send to > Compressed folder, I get a warning message saying the empty folder was omitted.

I'm loading the resulting zip file into an application that runs on Apache Tomcat. This application throws errors for every single file contained in the zip that I produced with ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory. The zip that I created manually through Windows explorer is read just fine.

I suspect the problem lies in the empty zipped folders, but haven't yet been able to definitively conclude this. If the empty folders are the cause, I'd need a way to use ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory excluding empty folders.

Comment: I have  no .NET 4.5, but from the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx): _"The directory structure from the file system is preserved in the archive. If the directory is empty, an empty archive is created."_ So this is by design. You either have to fix it in the comsuming app on tomcat or you have to create a temporary folder which just contains the non-empty folders if possible. I haven't found a way to exclude empty folders in `CreateFromDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Zipping via temp seems a workable solution. If you put this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from my comment above:

I have no .NET 4.5, but from the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx): *"The directory structure from the file system is preserved in the archive. If the directory is empty, an empty archive is created."* So this is by design.

So you either have to

- fix it in the comsuming app on tomcat or you have to
- create a temporary folder which just contains the non-empty folders, if possible

I haven't found a way to exclude empty folders in `CreateFromDirectory` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I can remove empty directories from the created zip file. Though this still causes errors in the Tomcat application.

```
        // compress and copy new zip
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dirtocopy.FullName, NewZipFilePath);
        using (ZipArchive za = ZipFile.Open(NewZipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            // only empty folders end with \
            List<ZipArchiveEntry> emptyFolders = (from ZipArchiveEntry zae in za.Entries
                                where zae.FullName.EndsWith("\\")
                                select zae).ToList<ZipArchiveEntry>();

            emptyFolders.ForEach((ZipArchiveEntry folder) => folder.Delete());
        }
```

Comment: If you want to maintain the exact structure (replace empty files with empty folders) in your code change `emptyFolders.ForEach(f => f.Delete());` with `emptyFolders.ForEach(f => { f.Delete(); za.CreateEntry(f.FullName.Substring(0, f.FullName.Length - 1) + "/"); });`